# Exception after capturing outbound packets with jdivert (Java bindings for WinDivert)

Tags: java, packet

I was trying to capture network taffic using jdivert
(https://github.com/ffalcinelli/jdivert)
Whenever I try to open the handle:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws WinDivertException {
        WinDivert w = new WinDivert("outbound");
        w.open(); //exception there

        Packet packet = w.recv();
        System.out.println(packet);

        w.close(); 
    }
```

It throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" WinDivertException{code=5, message='null'}
    at com.github.ffalcinelli.jdivert.exceptions.WinDivertException.throwExceptionOnGetLastError(WinDivertException.java:57)
    at com.github.ffalcinelli.jdivert.WinDivert.open(WinDivert.java:112)
    at pl.alpaq.lab.packets.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your exception output : **WinDivertException{code=5, message='null'}**

According to the  [windivert faq page](https://www.reqrypt.org/windivert-faq.html) , code 5 is a permission error code.

Are you running your console/shell with admin rights?